Computing an expected value of a product of elements of the sample covariance matrix in two different ways with conflicting results.
Let $ N, T \ge 1 $ be integers and
let $C:= {\tilde C}  \cdot {\tilde C}^T $ be a positive definite  matrix of size $N \times N $:

Then let $ c:= X \cdot X^T $ where $X = {\tilde C} \cdot Z $ with
$$
Z:= \left( Z_{i,\xi} \right)_{i=1,\xi=1}^{N,T}
$$
independent indenticaly distributed sampled from $N(0,1)$.
Note that we have
$$
E\left[ X_{i,\xi} X_{j,\eta} \right] = C_{i,j}
\delta_{\xi,\eta}
$$
for $i,j=1,\cdots,N$ and $\xi,\eta=1,\cdots,T$.
Now, we define the sample covariance matrix as $ c:= X \cdot X^T $  and we fix $(i,j) $ such that $1 \le i \le N$ and $1 \le j \le N$ and the question is to compute $E \left[ c_{i,j} \cdot c_{j,i} \right] $.
We will compute that in two different ways and we will obtain conflicting results.

First way  (Wick-Isserlis' theorem):
\begin{eqnarray}
E \left[ c_{i,j} \cdot c_{j,i} \right] &=&
\sum\limits_{\xi=1}^T \sum\limits_{\xi_1=1}^T E\left[ X_{i,\xi} X_{j,\xi} X_{j,\xi_1} X_{i,\xi_1} \right] \\
&=& \sum\limits_{\xi=1}^T \sum\limits_{\xi_1=1}^T
\left(
E\left[ X_{i,\xi} X_{j,\xi} \right] E\left[ X_{j,\xi_1} X_{i,\xi_1} \right]
+
E\left[ X_{i,\xi} X_{j,\xi_1} \right] E\left[ X_{j,\xi} X_{i,\xi_1} \right]
+
E\left[ X_{i,\xi} X_{i,\xi_1} \right] E\left[ X_{j,\xi} X_{j,\xi_1} \right]
\right) \\
&=&
C_{i,j} C_{j,i} \cdot T^2 + C_{i,j} C_{j,i} \cdot T^1 + C_{i,i} C_{j,j} T \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}
I know from other considerations that this result is correct!
Second way (differentiating the Laplace transform):
It is known (see equation (1) in
Letac, Gérard; Massam, Hélène, The Laplace transform ((\det s)^{-p} \exp \operatorname{tr}(s^{-1}w)) and the existence of non-central Wishart distributions, J. Multivariate Anal. 163, 96-110 (2018). ZBL1386.60068.)
that the Laplace transform of the sample covariance matrix reads $E \left[ e^{-Tr[\Theta \cdot c] } \right] = \det(1_N + 2 C \cdot \Theta)^{-T/2} $ . Here $ \Theta $ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.

As a matter of fact  we give the derivation of the Laplace transform below. Let $c(Z):= \sum\limits_{\xi=1}^T (\vec{Z}_\xi + \vec{m}_\xi) \cdot  (\vec{Z}_\xi + \vec{m}_\xi)^T $ where $\vec{m}_\xi $ is the vector of drifts (expected values of returns0 at time $\xi$).
We also define ${\mathfrak a}:= \sum\limits_{\xi=1}^T \vec{m}_\xi \cdot \vec{m}_\xi^T $ as the matrix of drifts.
Then we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
E \left[ e^{-Tr[\Theta \cdot c] } \right] &=&
\int\limits_{{\mathbb R}^{N T}}
e^{-Tr[\Theta. c(Z)]}
\cdot 
\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{\xi=1}^T \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \sum\limits_{j=1}^N (C^{-1})_{i,j} Z_{i,\xi} Z_{j,\xi} }
}{
\sqrt{2\pi}^{N T} \sqrt{\det(C)}^T
}
\cdot \left(
\prod\limits_{j=1}^N
\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^T d Z_{j,\xi} 
\right) \\
&=&
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}^{N T}}
\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^T
\int\limits_{{\mathbb R}^N}
e^{-Tr[\Theta\cdot ({\tilde C} \vec{Z}_\xi+\vec{m}_\xi)\cdot (\vec{Z}_\xi^T \cdot {\tilde C}^T + \vec{m}_\xi^T)]}
\cdot
e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^N Z_{j,\xi}^2}
\cdot 
\left(\prod\limits d Z_{j,\xi}\right) \\
&=&
\frac{e^{-Tr[\Theta \cdot {\mathfrak a}]}}{\sqrt{2\pi}^{N T}}
\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^T
\int\limits_{{\mathbb R}^N}
e^{- \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \sum\limits_{j=1}^N ({\tilde C}^T \cdot \Theta \cdot {\tilde C})_{i,j} Z_{i,\xi} Z_{j,\xi} }
\cdot 
e^{-\vec{m}_\xi^T \cdot (\Theta+\Theta^T)\cdot {\tilde C} \cdot \vec{Z}_\xi}
\cdot
e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^N Z_{j,\xi}^2}
\cdot 
\left(\prod\limits d Z_{j,\xi}\right) \\
&=&
\frac{e^{-Tr[\Theta \cdot {\mathfrak a}]}}{\sqrt{2\pi}^{N T}}
\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^T
\int\limits_{{\mathbb R}^N}
e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \sum\limits_{j=1}^N (1_N + 2 {\tilde C}^T \cdot \Theta \cdot {\tilde C})_{i,j} Z_{i,\xi} Z_{j,\xi} }
\cdot 
e^{-\vec{m}_\xi^T \cdot (\Theta+\Theta^T)\cdot {\tilde C} \cdot \vec{Z}_\xi}
\cdot 
\left(\prod\limits d Z_{j,\xi}\right) \\
&=&
\frac{e^{-Tr[\Theta \cdot {\mathfrak a}]}}{\sqrt{2\pi}^{N T}}
\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^T
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}^N}{\sqrt{\det(1_N + 2 {\tilde C}^T \cdot \Theta \cdot {\tilde C})}} 
\cdot 
e^{\frac{1}{2} \vec{m}_\xi \cdot (\Theta + \Theta^T) \cdot {\tilde C} \cdot (1_N + 2 {\tilde C}^T \Theta {\tilde C})^{-1} \cdot {\tilde C}^T \cdot (\Theta+\Theta^T)\cdot \vec{m}_\xi}
\\
&=&
\det(1_N + 2 {\tilde C}^T \cdot \Theta \cdot {\tilde C})^{-\frac{T}{2}} \cdot e^{-Tr[\Theta \cdot {\mathfrak a}]}
\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^T
e^{\frac{1}{4} \vec{m}_\xi^T (\Theta+\Theta^T) (\frac{1}{2} C^{-1} + \Theta)^{-1} \cdot (\Theta+\Theta^T) \cdot \vec{m}_\xi}
\\
&=&
\det(1_N + 2 C \cdot \Theta )^{-\frac{T}{2}} \cdot 
\cdot e^{-Tr[\Theta \cdot {\mathfrak a}]}
e^{\frac{1}{4}  Tr[ (\Theta+\Theta^T) (\frac{1}{2} C^{-1} + \Theta)^{-1} \cdot (\Theta+\Theta^T) \cdot {\mathfrak a}]} \\
&=&
\det(1_N + 2 C \cdot \Theta )^{-\frac{T}{2}} \cdot 
\cdot 
e^{- Tr[\frac{1}{2} C^{-1}\cdot (\frac{1}{2} C^{-1} + \Theta)^{-1} \cdot \Theta \cdot {\mathfrak a}]}
\end{eqnarray}
The first line above is just the definition of the expected value.
In the second line we substituted for ${\tilde C}^{-1} Z$ and then , owing to the fact that the returns at different times are independent, we factored the result over time.
In the third line we used the cyclic property of the trace.
In the fourth line we completed to the square and in the fifth line we carried out the Gaussian integrals.

In view of the above we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
E\left[ c_{i,j} c_{j,i} \right] &=&
\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_{j,i}}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_{i,j}} 
E \left[ e^{-Tr[\Theta \cdot c] } \right] \right|_{\Theta=0} \\
&=&
\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_{j,i}}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_{i,j}} 
\det(1_N + 2 C \cdot \Theta)^{-T/2}  \right|_{\Theta=0} \\
&=&
(-\frac{T}{2})_{(1)} \cdot \det\left(1_N + 2 C \cdot \Theta\right)^{-\frac{T}{2}-1} \cdot \\
&&
\left(
\sum\limits_{I=1}^N \sum\limits_{J=1,J\neq I}^N
\det\left.(1_N + 2 C \cdot \Theta)\right|_{
\begin{array}{lll}
I \rightarrow 2 C_{I,j} \vec{e}_i \\
J \rightarrow 2 C_{J,i} \vec{e}_j
\end{array}
}
\right) + \\
&&
(-\frac{T}{2})_{(2)} \cdot \det\left(1_N + 2 C \cdot 
\Theta\right)^{-\frac{T}{2}-2} 
\cdot  \\
&&
\left.
\left(
\sum\limits_{I=1}^N \sum\limits_{J=1}^N
\det\left.(1_N + 2 C \cdot \Theta)\right|_{I \rightarrow 2 C_{I,j} \vec{e}_i} \cdot
\det\left.(1_N + 2 C \cdot \Theta)\right|_{J \rightarrow 2 C_{J,i} \vec{e}_j}
\right)
\right|_{\Theta \rightarrow 0}
\\
&=&
(-\frac{T}{2})_{(1)} \cdot \left[ 4 C_{i,j} C_{j,i} - 4 C_{i,i} C_{j,j} \right] +
(-\frac{T}{2})_{(2)} \cdot \left[ 4 C_{i,j} C_{j,i}\right] \\
&=&
C_{i,j} C_{j,i} T^2 + 2 T C_{i,i} C_{j,j} \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}
In the third line from the top we introduced a notation $I \rightarrow \cdots$ which means that the $I$th row is being replaced by the right hand side.
Now it turns out that in the first double sum the only non-zero terms are $(I,J) = (i,j)$ and $(I,J)=(j,i)$  with the term in sum being equal to $4 C_{i,j} C_{j,i} $ and to $-4 C_{i,i} C_{j,j} $.
Likewise in the second double sum the only non-zero terms is $(I,J)=(i,j) $ with the term in sum being equal to $4 C_{i,j} C_{j,i} $.
As always the code snippet below validates the two conflicting results.
(*Problem: 

Let c be the sample covariance matrix in a central Wishart population \
with the scale matrix being an identity.

We compute E[Subscript[(c), i,j]Subscript[(c), j,i]] in two different \
ways and we are getting conflicting results.

Why?!!!

*)
{NN, T} = {2, 2}; mprec = 50;
CC = RandomReal[{1, 3}, {NN, NN}, WorkingPrecision -> mprec]; CC = 
 Transpose[CC] . 
  DiagonalMatrix[RandomReal[{1, 3}, NN, WorkingPrecision -> mprec]] . 
  CC; CC += +IdentityMatrix[NN];
CCt = Transpose[CholeskyDecomposition[CC]];
X = CCt . Table[Z[i, \[Xi]], {i, 1, NN}, {\[Xi], 1, T}];
PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[CC]

(*Here (from Wick-Isserlis) we have  CC[[i,j]] CC[[j,i]] (T^2+T) + \
CC[[i,i]]CC[[j,j]]T *)
res1a = Table[
  NIntegrate[
    Sum[X[[j, \[Xi]]] X[[i, \[Xi]]] X[[i, \[Xi]1]] X[[j, \[Xi]1]], {\
\[Xi], 1, T}, {\[Xi]1, 1, 
       T}] Exp[-1/2  Sum[Z[j, \[Xi]]^2, {j, 1, NN}, {\[Xi], 1, T}]], 
    Evaluate[
     Sequence @@ 
      Flatten[Table[{Z[j, \[Xi]], -Infinity, Infinity}, {j, 1, 
         NN}, {\[Xi], 1, T}], 1]]] 1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])^(NN  T), {i, 1, 
   NN}, {j, 1, NN}]
res1b = Table[
   CC[[i, j]]  CC[[j, i]]  (T^2 + T) + CC[[i, i]] CC[[j, j]] T, {i, 1,
     NN}, {j, 1, NN}];
(res1a/res1b - 1) // MatrixForm

Clear[\[Theta]];
(*Here we have (differentiating the Laplace transform) we have \
CC[[i,j]] CC[[j,i]] (T^2) + CC[[i,i]]CC[[j,j]]2T *)
Th = Table[\[Theta][i, j], {i, 1, NN}, {j, 1, NN}];
res2a = Table[
   D[1/Sqrt[Det[IdentityMatrix[NN] + 2 CC . Th]^T], {\[Theta][i, j], 
     1}, {\[Theta][j, i], 1}], {i, 1, NN}, {j, 1, 
    NN}] /. \[Theta][__] :> 0
res2b = Table[
   CC[[i, j]]  CC[[j, i]]  (T^2) + CC[[i, i]] CC[[j, j]] 2 T, {i, 1, 
    NN}, {j, 1, NN}];
(res2a/res2b - 1) // MatrixForm



The question is why is the second result incorrect?!

Note that both matrices  $c$ and $C$ are symmetric and as such , when differentiating , one has to take into account all possible ordering of pairs of indices. In other words we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
E\left[ c_{i,j} c_{j,i} \right] &=&
\left.
\frac{1}{4}
\left(
  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \Theta_{i,j}^2} + 
2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \Theta_{i,j} \partial \Theta_{j,i} } +
  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \Theta_{j,i}^2}
\right)
\det\left(1_N + 2 C \cdot \Theta \right)^{-\frac{T}{2}}
\right|_{\Theta = 0} \\
&=&
C_{i,j} C_{j,i} (T^2+T) + T C_{i,i} C_{j,j}
\end{eqnarray}
This is the correct result when compared with  the outcome of hte Wick-Isserlis' theorem based calculation.
Again, the code snippet below verifies the solution with Mathematica.
NN = RandomInteger[{2, 7}]; T =.; i =.; j =.;
substsym := C[i_, j_] :> C[j, i] /; i > j;
Th = Table[\[Theta][ii, jj], {ii, 1, NN}, {jj, 1, NN}];
CC = Table[C[ii, ji], {ii, 1, NN}, {ji, 1, NN}];
ex = Det[IdentityMatrix[NN] + 2 CC . Th]^(-T/2);
mat1 = Table[((D[ex, {\[Theta][i, j], 2}] + 
          2 D[ex, {\[Theta][i, j], 1}, {\[Theta][j, i], 1}] +  
          D[ex, {\[Theta][j, i], 2}] )/4 /. \[Theta][__] :> 0 /. 
      substsym), {i, 1, NN}, {j, 1, NN}] // Simplify;
(mat1 /. C[i_, j_] :> Subscript[C, i, j]) // MatrixForm
mat2 = Table[(C[i, j] C[j, i] (T^2 + T) + T  C[i, i] C[j, j]) /. 
    substsym, {i, 1, NN}, {j, 1, NN}];
(mat1 - mat2) // Simplify


In the same way we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
E\left[ c_{i,j} c_{j,k} c_{k,i} \right] &=& \left.- \frac{1}{8}
 [\frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_{i,j}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_{j,i}} ]
 [\frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_{j,k}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_{k,j}} ]
[\frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_{k,i}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \Theta_{i,k}} ]
\det\left(1_N + 2 C \cdot \Theta \right)^{-\frac{T}{2}} \right|_{\Theta=0}\\
&=&
C_{i,j} C_{j,k} C_{k,i} (T^3+3 T^2 + 4 T)+ \\
&&
(C_{i,i} C_{j,k} C_{k,i} + C_{j,j} C_{i,k} C_{k,i} + C_{k,k} C_{i,j} C_{j,i})(T^2+T) + \\
&&
C_{i,i} C_{j,j} C_{k,k} T
\end{eqnarray}
Just as before, the code snippet verifies the result. Here we go:
binary[n_] := 
  NestWhileList[
    QuotientRemainder[#[[1]], 2] &, {n}, # != {0, 0} &][[2 ;; -2, 
    2]];
substsym := C[i_, j_] :> C[j, i] /; i > j;
NN = 4;
nn = Length[inds];
Th = Table[\[Theta][ii, jj], {ii, 1, NN}, {jj, 1, NN}];
CC = Table[C[ii, ji], {ii, 1, NN}, {ji, 1, NN}];
ex = Det[IdentityMatrix[NN] + 2 CC . Th]^(-T/2);
mat1 = Table[
   With[{inds = {i, j, k}},
    (-1)^
      nn  Collect[(Sum[
           D[ex, Evaluate[
             Sequence @@ With[{imask = PadRight[binary[ii], nn]},
               
               Table[{\[Theta][
                  inds[[myMod[
                    If[imask[[\[Xi]]] == 0, \[Xi], \[Xi] + 1], nn]]], 
                  inds[[myMod[
                    If[imask[[\[Xi]]] == 0, \[Xi] + 1, \[Xi]], nn]]]],
                  1}, {\[Xi], 1, nn}]
               ]]], {ii, 0, 2^nn - 1}] /. \[Theta][__] :> 0 /. 
         substsym)  1/2^nn, T, Simplify]
    ]
   , {i, 1, NN}, {j, 1, NN}, {k, 1, NN}];
(mat1 /. C[i_, j_] :> Subscript[C, i, j]) // MatrixForm
mat2 = Table[
    C[i, j] C[j, k] C[k, 
       i]  (T^3 + 3  T^2 + 4 T) + (C[i, i] C[j, k] C[k, j] + 
        C[j, j] C[i, k] C[k, i] + C[k, k] C[i, j] C[j, i]) (T^2 + T) +
      C[i, i] C[j, j] C[k, k] T
    , {i, 1, NN}, {j, 1, NN}, {k, 1, NN}] /. substsym;
(mat1 - mat2) // Simplify



I cannot read your long message, but you must be aware that the Lebesgue measure $\lambda(dS)$ on symmetric matrices of order $n$ that we use in our paper with Helene is the one which gives to the unit cube the mass one, where the unit cube is associated to the inner product of symmetric matrices $\langle A,B\rangle$ =trace $AB.$ This Lebesgue measure is
proportional  but not equal to the ordinary one  $dS$ used in Muirhead for instance. For instance if $$S(a,b,c)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\b&c\end{array}\right]$$ a unit cube constructed from the orthonormal basis
$$S_1=S(1,0,0),\  S_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}S(0,1,0),\ S_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}S(0,0,1)$$ is such that $1=\int_{C}\lambda(dS)$ by definition but $\int_Cdadbdc= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$ This choice of $\lambda$ is useful for the theoretical calculations, but is a source de discrepancy with the results of practioners. Therefore it may be the explanation.

Gerard: Thanks for getting in touch. I started reading your paper and I find it very interesting. I would like to discuss computing the topic of computing the joint distribution of eigenvalues (latent roots) of non-central Wishart matrices. I will write you an email on this if you do not mind.
